# How to access to a variable inside another view?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to access to the value of variables in different views and get a sum of them. I tried to do it in different ways using environmentObject and Binding variables but failed.

I have example of two different views as follows:

First View:

```
struct questionOne: View {
    @State var isSelected = false

    @State var score1 = 0

    func onClick() {
        score1 += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            Button(action: {self.onClick(); self.isSelected.toggle()}) {
                Text("AAA")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second View:

```
struct questionTwo: View {
    @State var isSelected = false

    @State var score2 = 0

    func onClick() {
        score2 += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            Button(action: {self.onClick(); self.isSelected.toggle()}) {
                Text("BBB")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a third view I'd like to take score1 variable from first view and score2 variable from second view and sum them up.

```
struct ResultPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Your score is \(score1) + \(score2)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@State` is using for the view itself. If you want to use a variable from outside of the view, you should consider using another wrapper like `@Binding`. I refactored your code and here is what its looks like now:

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    let text: String
    @State var isSelected = false
    @Binding var score: Int

    var body: some View {
        Button(text) { self.score += 1; self.isSelected.toggle() }
    }
}
```

So now `QuestionView` is reusable enough to pass it's needed arguments like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var score1 = 0
    @State var score2 = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(score1) - \(score2)")
            QuestionView(text: "AAA", score: $score1)
            QuestionView(text: "BBB", score: $score1)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, now the responsibility of maintaining `score`s is on the parent view. So it has access to them and it can use them.

Comment: Thanks! Your way is much more elegant.

Comment: So is it what you were looking for?

Comment: I got what I wanted with the global variable version. But in the future, for more complex apps I will use your way for sure.

Comment: Yes it works. Although it's not *how you access to a variable inside another view* as question asked. It's global and it's like a workaround. Try not to use too much global variables.

Answer (score -1):

I have declared the variables outside of the view controllers just under import SwiftUI. That way I could accessed to their values.

Comment: That is *global variable*. They will persist in your app until you close the app entirely. So I don't think it is a good idea. You can just pass your variables in and out as I mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59010312/5623035)